# My own class, with an instance, but getting "An object reference is required"

Tags: c#

I'm trying to learn C#. I've done a couple of online courses, and I'm trying to just create some *really* basic code without the tutorials now to embed what I've learned.… and I'm not doing so well :-(

My apologies if this is too basic a question or has been answered before - I've done a search for "An object reference is required" and in most cases the issue seems to be that someone is trying to use an instance method like a static method,  but that's not (I think) what I've done...

I'm trying to do something really basic - create a Dictionary to contain Person objects, with a method to allow adding a person which also returns the current count of items in the dictionary.

Here's the code:

```
public class TestClass
{
    private Dictionary<string, Person> peopleList;

    public TestClass()
    {
        peopleList = new Dictionary<string, Person>();
    }
    public static int AddPerson(Person p)
    {
        peopleList.Add(p.Name, p);
        return peopleList.Count;
    }

}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

}
```

I also have the following statement at the top:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

In my code, I've tried to create a constructor to initialise the Dictionary object, but whenever I attempt to use peopleList, (in AddPerson) I'm getting "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'TestClass.peopleList'".

I've also tried initialising the field without the use of the constructor, as follows:

```
    private Dictionary<string, Person> peopleList = new Dictionary<string, Person>();
```

but got the same issue.

I know I've missed something obvious... but can't spot it. Can anyone help?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: OK why is AddPerson static? surely you want that linked to the instance of your class so you could maybe have 2 lists? Secondly, if you called the static it wouldnt have a list to connect to.. as welll as you havent shown making the person you add

Comment: For beginners: unfortunately, `Main()` has to be static. But in your own code you should avoid `static` as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make members and methods static if they are to used from a static method.

```
public class TestClass
{
    private static Dictionary<string, Person> peopleList;

    public static TestClass()
    {
        peopleList = new Dictionary<string, Person>();
    }
    public static int AddPerson(Person p)
    {
        peopleList.Add(p.Name, p);
        return peopleList.Count;
    }    
}
```

If you don't, you're trying to access and instance member / method from a method that's invoked without an instance. This makes no sense, and cannot work. The compiler is telling you this.

The alternative (and a better option in this case) is to make none of it static. Then you'll also get correct behavior:

```
public class TestClass
{
    private Dictionary<string, Person> peopleList;

    public TestClass()
    {
        peopleList = new Dictionary<string, Person>();
    }
    public int AddPerson(Person p)
    {
        peopleList.Add(p.Name, p);
        return peopleList.Count;
    }    
}
```

If you do this, however, you'll have to create an instance of `TestClass` to call the `AddPerson` method on.

Comment: Okay - thanks. Sorry - too many new keywords and ideas floating round in my brain and not in order yet. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I posted my answer just as you edited yours. Deleting it now

Answer (score 0):

Or you can create a class static which take care of adding element.

```
public static class Util
{
    public static int AddPerson(Person p, Dictionary<string, Person> list)
    {
        list.Add(p.Name, p);
        return list.Count;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the responses from other people here but I think they might not clarify your problem to you because you might not know what 'static' means in code. So let's begin there.

When you have an object:

```
public class A() 
{
    public string Code { get;set; }
}
```

This object has to be instantiated in order to access its property 'Code'.
Meaning, that property Code is linked to the instantiated object 'A'.

But static is used to make a method, property or object accessible without having the objected to be instantiated. Meaning, these items are always available without an instantiated object. And if they have a reference to an instantiated object, this can pose a problem when you call that method when it's not instantiated.

This happens in your example.

(TLDR;) What would simply solve your problem, is removing the 'static' from the method.

Or, if you wish to use this method as a static, you need to extend it like so:

```
public static int AddPerson(TestClass testClass, Person p)
{
    testClass.PeopleList.Add(p.Name, p);
    return testClass.PeopleList.Count;
}
```

But this also requires you to expose PeopleList in the class in order to access it. This is because when making a static method, it does not belong to an instance of the object, but simply belongs to all and none of the instances of the object. It exists, outside it.